# Почему всё видео h265 весит меньше видеопотока?

Tags: ffmpeg, сжатие, кодек

Я перекодировал видео h264 в h265 командой ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i h264.mkv -c:v libx265 -crf 17 -c:a copy h265.mkv`

После этого я открыл mediainfo и очень удивился. **Вес видеопотока был больше, чем вес самого файла.**

Собственно, сам вопрос: **С чем это связано?**

У меня несколько предположений:

1. Это нововведение h265
2. x265 неправильно закодировал
3. Mediainfo неправильно прочитал файл

UDP: Конечное видео полностью рабочее.

Прикладываю вывод Mediainfo:

```
Общее
Уникальный идентификатор                 : 180191431166542781927570955498930338345 (0x878F9B780CBB949AEA3D81E4AF887A29)
Полное имя                               : E:\h265.mkv
Формат                                   : Matroska
Версия формата                           : Version 4
Размер файла                             : 1,38 Гбайт
Продолжительность                        : 51 м. 30 с.
Общий поток                              : 3 829 Кбит/сек
Название фильма                          : None
Программа кодирования                    : Lavf59.17.101
Библиотека кодирования                   : Lavf59.17.101
ErrorDetectionType                       : Per level 1

Видео
Идентификатор                            : 1
Формат                                   : HEVC
Формат/Информация                        : High Efficiency Video Coding
Профиль формата                          : Main@L4@Main
Идентификатор кодека                     : V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC
Продолжительность                        : 51 м. 30 с.
Битрейт                                  : 8 688 Кбит/сек
Ширина                                   : 1 920 пикселей
Высота                                   : 960 пикселей
Соотношение сторон                       : 2,000
Режим частоты кадров                     : Постоянный
Частота кадров                           : 24,000 кадра/сек
Цветовое пространство                    : YUV
Субдискретизация насыщенности            : 4:2:0 (Type 0)
Битовая глубина                          : 8 бит
Бит/(Пиксели*Кадры)                      : 0.196
Размер потока                            : 3,13 Гбайт
Библиотека кодирования                   : x265 3.5+20-17839cc0d:[Windows][GCC 11.2.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
Настройки программы                      : cpuid=1049583 / frame-threads=3 / numa-pools=8 / wpp / no-pmode / no-pme / no-psnr / no-ssim / log-level=2 / input-csp=1 / input-res=1920x960 / interlace=0 / total-frames=0 / level-idc=0 / high-tier=1 / uhd-bd=0 / ref=3 / no-allow-non-conformance / no-repeat-headers / annexb / no-aud / no-eob / no-eos / no-hrd / info / hash=0 / no-temporal-layers / open-gop / min-keyint=24 / keyint=250 / gop-lookahead=0 / bframes=4 / b-adapt=2 / b-pyramid / bframe-bias=0 / rc-lookahead=20 / lookahead-slices=6 / scenecut=40 / no-hist-scenecut / radl=0 / no-splice / no-intra-refresh / ctu=64 / min-cu-size=8 / no-rect / no-amp / max-tu-size=32 / tu-inter-depth=1 / tu-intra-depth=1 / limit-tu=0 / rdoq-level=0 / dynamic-rd=0.00 / no-ssim-rd / signhide / no-tskip / nr-intra=0 / nr-inter=0 / no-constrained-intra / strong-intra-smoothing / max-merge=3 / limit-refs=1 / no-limit-modes / me=1 / subme=2 / merange=57 / temporal-mvp / no-frame-dup / no-hme / weightp / no-weightb / no-analyze-src-pics / deblock=0:0 / sao / no-sao-non-deblock / rd=3 / selective-sao=4 / early-skip / rskip / no-fast-intra / no-tskip-fast / no-cu-lossless / b-intra / no-splitrd-skip / rdpenalty=0 / psy-rd=2.00 / psy-rdoq=0.00 / no-rd-refine / no-lossless / cbqpoffs=0 / crqpoffs=0 / rc=crf / crf=17.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpstep=4 / stats-write=0 / stats-read=0 / ipratio=1.40 / pbratio=1.30 / aq-mode=2 / aq-strength=1.00 / cutree / zone-count=0 / no-strict-cbr / qg-size=32 / no-rc-grain / qpmax=69 / qpmin=0 / no-const-vbv / sar=1 / overscan=0 / videoformat=5 / range=0 / colorprim=2 / transfer=2 / colormatrix=2 / chromaloc=1 / chromaloc-top=0 / chromaloc-bottom=0 / display-window=0 / cll=0,0 / min-luma=0 / max-luma=255 / log2-max-poc-lsb=8 / vui-timing-info / vui-hrd-info / slices=1 / no-opt-qp-pps / no-opt-ref-list-length-pps / no-multi-pass-opt-rps / scenecut-bias=0.05 / hist-threshold=0.03 / no-opt-cu-delta-qp / no-aq-motion / no-hdr10 / no-hdr10-opt / no-dhdr10-opt / no-idr-recovery-sei / analysis-reuse-level=0 / analysis-save-reuse-level=0 / analysis-load-reuse-level=0 / scale-factor=0 / refine-intra=0 / refine-inter=0 / refine-mv=1 / refine-ctu-distortion=0 / no-limit-sao / ctu-info=0 / no-lowpass-dct / refine-analysis-type=0 / copy-pic=1 / max-ausize-factor=1.0 / no-dynamic-refine / no-single-sei / no-hevc-aq / no-svt / no-field / qp-adaptation-range=1.00 / scenecut-aware-qp=0conformance-window-offsets / right=0 / bottom=0 / decoder-max-rate=0 / no-vbv-live-multi-pass
Язык                                     : German
Default                                  : Да
Forced                                   : Нет
Цветовой диапазон                        : Limited
```

Comment: А почему файл должен весить больше потока? сжатие данных - не? т.е. ваше видео весит 3.13гб, после СЖАТИЯ получился файл размером 1.3гб =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков если я правильно понял суть вопроса — это информация об одном и том же файле, то есть оба размера относятся к файлу после сжатия

Comment: Мой Mediainfo v21.09 вообще не выводит размер потока

Comment: А вообще народ считает это багом https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo/issues/392